# AngularJS: $on doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to make it possible to edit user name in modal window using AngularJS, however, after I use "update()" function from my second controller, name remains the same. `$scope.closeThisDialog();` works fine. What's wrong with my `$on` and `$emit`?

My service:

```
  'use strict';
    var myService = function () {
        var user = { name: "Peter", surname: "Pitt"};   
        var service = {};
        service.user = user;
        return service;
    };
    module.exports = [myService];
```

First controller:

```
    'use strict';   
    var FirstController = function ($scope, myService, ngDialog) {   
        $scope.user = myService.user;   
        $scope.openModal = function () {
            ngDialog.open({templateUrl: 'myTemplate'});
        };  
        $scope.$on("updateUser", function(event, data){
            $scope.user = data;
        });
    };
    module.exports = ['$scope', 'myService', 'ngDialog', FirstController];
```

Second controller:

```
'use strict'; 
var SecondController = function ($scope, myService, ngDialog) {
    $scope.editedUser = angular.copy(myService.user); 
    $scope.update = function () {
            $scope.$emit("updateUser", $scope.editedUser);
            $scope.closeThisDialog();
        };
    };    
    module.exports = ['$scope', 'myService', 'ngDialog', SecondController];
```

index file:

```
<html>
<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <a ng-click="openModal()">Edit</a>
        Name: {{user.name}} </br>
        Surname: {{user.surname}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and modal window:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
    <form ng-controller="SecondController">
        <input ng-model="editedUser.name">
        <input ng-model="editedUser.surname">
        <button ng-click="update()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</script>
```

Comment: need to look how you placed this controllers in html? or are they on different page?

Comment: Yes, please show HTML as well.

Comment: I suppose you could try $broadcast from $rootScope rather than $emit from child scope.

Comment: @pankajparkar: ok, my minified html is added.

Comment: You aren't showing where `$scope.closeThisDialog()` is defined - never mind, I see that the library offers that method.

Comment: @pherris:  https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#scopeclosethisdialogvalue

Comment: yep :) just saw my mistake - did you try passing scope: $scope in your call to ngDialog.open? :`ngDialog.open({
    template: 'myTemplate',
    scope: $scope
});` Try that, then try emitting on `$scope.$parent` e.g. `$scope.$parent.$emit("updateUser", $scope.editedUser);` (I think this second step will be required, but not 100% sure, you might be able to emit on $scope - try both)

Comment: @pherris: thanks! `scope: $scope` fixed my problem :)

Comment: cool, posted answer - also, noticed that since you are now sharing $scope you may not have to emit anything - I think you should just be able to edit the $scope.user object directly in your modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass the $scope into `ngDialog.open` so that you are emitting on the same scope you are listening on:

```
ngDialog.open({ template: 'myTemplate', scope: $scope });
```

of course, since you are now sharing the same scope, you should just be able to edit `$scope.user` directly in the modal and not bother emitting/listening for events at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$emit` only echo's the event up the scope chain. So your first controller would only hear if it it's scope was a parent (or parents parent etc...) of your second controller.

In order for the event to work you'll have to use `$rootScope.$on` (capture everything going up) in your first controller OR `$rootScope.$broadcast` (send event to every child scope) in your second controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without using the $emit and $broadcast if you just want the data to be updated in the FirstController by replacing

```
$scope.update = function () {
        $scope.$emit("updateUser", $scope.editedUser);
        $scope.closeThisDialog();
    };
};
```

with

```
 $scope.update = function () {
        angular.copy($scope.editedUser,myService.user); 
        $scope.closeThisDialog();
    };
});
```

You can see a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/re4z6z6n/4/)